# Empty intersection counting

Tags: algorithm, linear-algebra

I am implementing a game of go on a board size of 7 x 7, w = white stones, b = black stones. I want to count the end result. Remember this is a made up go game, we only count empty cells that are surrounded by black or white stones.

```
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
0    b
1    b w  
2b b w   w
3  w       w
4    w     w
5      w w w
6
```

I want to count all the intersection surrounded by w and b, that means I want to count cells 2,3 3,2  3,3 3,4 4,3 4,4 for white stones and 0,0 0,1 1,0 1,1 for black stones. All the algorithms I came up with are too complicated.

I will implement the final solution using GNU assembler. I just started learning assembly language so I don't want it to be complicated. The algorithm can use loops and arrays, but no recursion or function calls.

I wanted to see if there is a simple algorithm in linear algebra to solve this problem, or I would appreciate it if you can describe a simple algorithm without the use of recursion and function calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A flood fill type algorithm might be applicable:

1. Find the first unassigned cell.
2. If the cell is empty, flood fill from it, stopping at edge cells or occupied cells.

   1. For the first occupied cell encountered, record the colour of the occupier.
   2. If an occupied cell encountered is a different colour, record that more than one colour is involved.
   3. After filling, if there was only one colour encountered, mark the whole area as belonging to that colour.  The number of empty cells in the area is added to the count.
3. Repeat from step 1 until all cells are assigned.

A flood fill is a fairly standard algorithm something like:

1. Push the start cell on a stack.
2. While the stack is not empty:

   1. Pop a cell from it.
   2. If the cell has not been processed yet (i.e. unassigned in this case):

      1. Process it (i.e. look at its colour in this case).
      2. Push all its neighbours on the stack.

Note that for these algorithms, it can make it easier if the board is surrounded by a layer of invisible "edge" cells.  Edge cells and occupied cells have no neighbours for the purpose of your algorithm.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Answer (score 0):

I would try an algorithm that travels along the edges of shapes formed by empty spaces like this:

1. Start at a piece which is adjacent to an empty space.
2. By testing all the adjacent spaces, travel along the outside edge of the shape formed by the empty spaces.
3. If you encounter the edge of the board, you are allowed to continue travelling along the edge of the board.
4. If you encounter both black and white pieces along the border of the shape, then the shape does not belong to any player.
5. Otherwise, the shape just outlined belongs to the player who owns all the border pieces.

You can then use the shapes to determine the number of spaces owned by each player.

Something more to think about since this question is tagged 'homework':  What is the result in this situation, and how can you account for it?

```
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
0
1  w w w w w w
2  w
3  w   b b b
4  w   b   b
5  w   b b b
6  w
```

Comment: thanks, in this situation, since all blacks are surrounded with whites, I would count all territory surrounded by whites including the black stones. can you describe how you go about doing step 2

Comment: Suppose i start on a piece which has an empty space to the left of it.  Then i test neighbors in an anti-clockwise direction starting from the left: bottom-left, bottom, bottom-right, right, top-right, top, top-left.  The first neighbour that has a piece, I travel there and repeat until I end up at the same place I started. I always test in a clockwise direction, but the starting space is determined by the direction I just travelled from.